# I am not able to fix the position of the footer in my website project

Tags: css

I wanted to fix the position of my header and footer for my project but the code of header is not working for the footer.
Here is the code i tried but its not working.

---

```
#footer{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:black;
color:white;
position:fixed;
}
```

Comment: #header{ position:fixed; width:100%; top:0px;} #footer{ position:fixed; width:100%; bottom:0px;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.container{
  min-height: 1000px;
}
#footer{
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  background:black;
  color:white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <footer id="footer"></footer>
</div>
```

Use this code. you are missing some css i.e `bottom`, `right` & `left` property which is essential if we are dealing with `fixed` or `absolute` position

Comment: What are these property you are talking about " left ,right, bottom "? Are these padding properties or something like that??

Comment: no this is not padding. this is space from directions. like i want my footer to stay 0px from bottom then i will use bottom:0; like above solution

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this.

```css
#footer,#header{
  padding:15px;
  background:#f00;
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
}
#footer{
  bottom:0px;
}
#header{
  top:0px;
}
.container{
  min-height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="footer">footer</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Style for footer

```
position: fixed !important;
width: 100% !important;
right: 0px !important;
bottom: 0px !important;
```

Style for Header

```
 position: fixed !important;
width: 100% !important;
right: 0px !important;
 left: 0px !important;
 top: 0px !important;
```

Comment: What are these properties "left right" you have talking about?

Comment: These are just for your easiness. we must deal left,top,right and bottom when we are working on Postion:Fixed this code work for me in my project. Try this hope this will work for you.